# Constructing c++ parameter pack from vector

Tags: c++, templates

Although my final use case is different, I essentially want to solve this prolem:

```
// Assumption: Length of the Fields is same as that of vector.
template<typename... Fields>
void Increment(const string &name, const std::vector<string> &fields) {

// *** How do I implement this function so that I can call something like:
// SpecializedCounter<typeof(Fields)...> counter = new Counter<typeof(fields)>();
// counter->Increment(name, field_pack);

}

template <typename... Fields>
class SpecializedCounter : public Counter<Fields...> {

  // public Counter provides a generalized interface for how to increment the counters.
  void Increment(const string &name, const Fields... &fields) {
      // I know how to implement this.
  }

};
```

The crux of the question is, how do I transform a list/vector or for that matter an iterable type to a parameter pack. I will be happy if this question is a dup! :)

Comment: The size of the vector/list isn't known at compile time, so that can't possibly work.

Comment: Added constraint so that the size of vector may be guessed.

Comment: A `vector` always homogenous, contains items of the same type so we can not exploit that the template type parameters can be different. From a vector you can pass only parameters of the same type. If so then it has no point of trying to call for example a function with `(string, string)` parameter list, then simply passing a `const vector<string>&` as a function parameter is more powerful. Maybe I just don't understand your goal...

Comment: This looks like a complicated work around dynamic_cast - it will not do better.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you're trying to do (at an application logic level), instead of how you think you can do it?

Comment: c# has 4 crosses, while c++ has only 2.